# Docker: How to save running instance?

Tags: docker

I am running an instance of docker, and I would like [to save my work](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/wiki/How-to-save-data) - the docs just aren't 100% clear on how to do this, so I'm asking here. I opened the docker instance using:

```
docker run -it [public dockerhub name]
```

Now I would like to save all my work locally so that I can come back to it. I don't particularly want to check it into dockerhub, unless that's advisable.

Here's what I have done. I have opened a new docker CLI tab, and done `docker ps` there to find the ID of the running docker instance. Then in the same tab I tried doing this:

```
docker commit <docker-id> me/myinstance
```

This gave me a commit hash.

Can I now safely exit the running docker instance? What command would I use to open it again - do I need to store the commit hash, or can I just do `docker run -it me/myinstance`?

Comment: yes just use this command and it will create a new container from the image you just create with al of your preview modifications

Comment: @CodeNotFound thanks and can I then run it again with `docker run -it me/myinstance`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes made inside a container are *not* lost when the container exits and containers (container applications) are not stateless unless you have specifically separated the data storage from the application (by mounting folders from the host filesystem or sending data to a database outside of the container).

To see your changes persisted in a container, start the old container (`docker start ~`) instead of creating a new container (`docker run ~`).

This is easier to do if you name your containers.

ie.

```
docker run -it --name containerName imageName
```

do stuff to your container

```
docker kill containerName
docker start containerName
```

You will see that your changes are persisted in that container.

You can also commit your container as an image, which can be pushed to a registry or exported to a file.

Answer (score 5):

As the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) mention:

- You pull an image from Docker hub
- You run that image on a container using `docker run <image>`

When you make changes to a container, you're not changing the underlying image, so those changes are not persisted if the container is stopped. To persist the changes you've made to the container, you create a new image with `docker commit <container_id>`

In the example that is on Docker docs:

```
# What containers are running on my system?
$ docker ps

ID                  IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED
c3f279d17e0a        ubuntu:12.04        /bin/bash           7 days ago
197387f1b436        ubuntu:12.04        /bin/bash           7 days ago

# Create a new image called svendowideit/testimage, tag it as "version3"
$ docker commit c3f279d17e0a  svendowideit/testimage:version3
f5283438590d

# What images do I have on my system?
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                        TAG                 ID
svendowideit/testimage            version3            f5283438590d
```

This way, you have persisted the changes to container `c3f279d17e0a`, on a new image, called `svendowideit/testimage:version3`.

Now you have an image with your modification, so you can run it as many times as you want on a container:

```
$ docker run svendowideit/testimage:version3
```

Again, containers are stateless. Any change you make inside a container, is lost when that container stops. One way to persist data even after a container exists, is by [using volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/). This way your container has access to a directory in the host filesystem, that you can read and write.

Comment: As a warning: be aware that `docker commit` does **not** apply to any volumes that are listed in the `VOLUME` section of your `Dockerfile`, unless you have them mapped with a `-v` option. I speak from frustrating experience until I found this hidden somewhere in official documentation.